# h2 close connection after Script.execute()

Tags: java, h2

I have an h2 database, I want generate the sql script and just after that rename this database.

I do something like that

```
        Script.execute("jdbc:h2:" + directory + File.separatorChar + dbName, user, password, file);
Date d = new Date();
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(d.getTime());
        File oldfile = new File(directory + File.separatorChar + dbName + ".h2.db");
        File newfile = new File(directory + File.separatorChar + t.getTime() + "backup.h2.db");
       oldfile.renameTo(newfile)
```

but rename failed ! I think it's cause Script open my database but how I can close it and rename my file just after ?
Thank's

Solution :
I just add after the `Script` command, thank's for your help

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + directory + File.separatorChar + dbName, user, password);
        conn.prepareStatement("SHUTDOWN DEFRAG;").execute();
        conn.close();
```

Comment: Can we see the actual error? If you are using Java 7, I suggest you switch to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29

Comment: actualy there is no error except the file can't be rename. I think Script lock my database but don't unlock when it's finish to execute so I can't rename it after, but if I don't execute, the file is rename with no probleme

Comment: Nothing is caught in the try block?

Comment: By using Files.move, I have a "process can't acces to the file cause it's used by another process" ... So yes Script don't seem to close it

Comment: I don't think the problem is the `Script` tool. Could you verify the source file exists, the target file doesn't exist, the file is not open otherwise? To do that, I suggest to comment the line starting with `Script.execute` and try again.

Comment: When I comment Script, I have no problem, the file is renamed... And if I test if file exist it's return me true.

Comment: and When it's caught the exception I have one "H2 Log Writer Thread" and one "H2 file lock watchdog"

Comment: Hm, which version of H2 do you use?